# How to show Laravel Nova(Version 4.0) action in Nova Resource Index?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Im new to nova framework .i need to use action method in Resource Index. According to documentation(https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/actions/defining-actions.html)" ,If an action is enabled for display on the resource's table row, you may also initiate the action from the resource's action dropdown menu via the resource index page. These actions are referred to as "Inline Actions":"
There is a public parameter for $showOnTableRow that you can set on the action.i used it in action nothing happens
And I can't find any documentation on that. Has anyone figured out how to do it?

Comment: in Index file do instantiate as         public function actions(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            (new PurchaseOrderAction())->showOnTableRow()


        ];
    }
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/registering-actions.html

Answer (score -1):

For laravel nova 4 you can use this method to show in the index
**->showOnIndex()**

Also if you want show only on Index use this method
**->onlyOnIndex()**